# GLFW how to ensure glfwTerminate is called when the program exits?

Tags: c++, signals, glfw

In GLFW documentation it is written that glfwTerminate will

> This will destroy any remaining window, monitor and cursor objects, restore any modified gamma ramps, re-enable the screensaver if it had been disabled and free any other resources allocated by GLFW.

and that one should call it before terminating the program. From my understanding that means, that if this function is not called the operating system doesn't have to re-enable the screensaver or restore modified gamma ramps, which is bad. How do I ensure that it is called regardless of how the program ends?

It's possible to use std::atexit to ensure it is called at the end if the program is exited via the exit command or by returning from the main function. It is also possible to do that making an object with a destructor in the main function that terminates when it is destroyed. The problem is what to do when the program ends with a signal. It's not possible to just register a function using std::signal, because glfwTerminate calls standard library functions other than the ones listed in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal which the site says is undefined behavior.

How do I ensure the program calls glfwTerminate? Or is it just not possible? And do I understand it correctly that without it the program can leave a modified gamma ramp after getting a signal? And are there any other ways the program can stop without calling the function?

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that the program will call glfwTerminate in case of segfaults or other undefined errors, so it is better to handle all errors before you decide to close it. So, recommendation is calling before the program terminates to restore the modified gamma ramps and re-enable the screensave.

Comment: How do I "handle" signals? How do I call glfwTerminate if I get SIGINT for example?

Comment: `#include <csignal>
#include <iostream>
#include <glfw/glfw3.h>

void signal_handler(int signal) {
    glfwTerminate();
    std::exit(signal);
}

int main() {
    // Register the signal handler for SIGINT
    std::signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);

    // Initialize GLFW and create a window...

    // Main loop...

    return 0;
}`

Comment: according to cppreference this is undefined behavior, because you are calling standard functions from signal handler